# Use subcomponent useImperativeHandle after usestate,

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Use the function of the subcomponent forwardRef after the usestate, there is a result, but it cannot be called successfully. After the usestate is cancelled, the function can be called successfully

parent:

```
      setProductId(ticket.id)
      orderPrePopRef &&  orderPrePopRef.current && orderPrePopRef.current.show()
```

child:

```
  const [showPop, toggleShowPop] = useState(false)
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    hide: () => {
      toggleShowPop(false)
    },
    show: () => {
      toggleShowPop(true)
      console.log(showPop) // true
    }
  }))
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(showPop) // false
  },[showPop])
```

When I use the code: setProductId(ticket.id) , the showpop in the subcomponent useEffect is false

When I comment the code: setProductId(ticket.id) , the showpop in the subcomponent useEffect is true

I need  When use the code: setProductId(ticket.id) , the showpop in the subcomponent useEffect is true